# Norm of two operators are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question

Let $\mathcal{H}^{\oplus n}$ denote the n-dimention Hilbert space. We define a operator liner operator
$A=[a_{i,j}]: \mathcal{H}^{\oplus n} \to \mathcal{H}^{\oplus n}$ by
$$
A\begin{bmatrix}
h_{1}\\
\vdots\\
h_{n}
\end{bmatrix}=
 \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{1k}h_{k}\\
  \vdots\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{nk}h_{k}.
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Define $A^t := [a_{j,i}].$ I am interested to know that
does the operator norm of $A$ and $A^t$ are same. For simple cases, I know that they are same. I will appreciate, If any body help me in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the norms of these maps are the same. I will use $\tilde A$ to refer to your map $A$ over $\mathcal H^{\oplus n}$ and $A$ to refer to the standard associated map over $\Bbb C^n$.

Consider the related linear map $T: \Bbb C^n \otimes \mathcal H\to \Bbb C^n \otimes \mathcal H$ given by $T = A \otimes \operatorname{id}_\mathcal{H}$, where $\otimes$ denotes a tensor product. I claim that the map $\phi:\mathcal H^{\oplus n} \to \Bbb C^n \otimes \mathcal H$ given by
$$
\phi(h_1,\dots,h_n) = h_1 \otimes e_1 + \cdots + h_n \otimes e_n
$$
is a bijective isometry of Hilbert spaces and that $T = \phi \circ \tilde A \circ \phi^{-1} = \phi \circ \tilde A \circ \phi^*$. So, $T$ and $\tilde A$ have the same norm.

For a tensor product of maps, it generally holds that $\|P \otimes Q\| = \|P\| \cdot \|Q\|$. Thus, we have
$$
\|\tilde A\| = \|T\| = \|A\| \cdot \|\operatorname{id}_{\mathcal H}\| = \|A\|.
$$
Similarly, $\|\widetilde{A^t}\| = \|A^t\|$. Since $\|A\| = \|A^t\|$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Dear Ben, may I know why $\Vert A\Vert= \Vert A^t \Vert.$

Comment: @Andy This is a well known fact about matrices. If $A$ is a matrix with real entries, then $\|A\|$ is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^tA$ (i.e. the largest singular value), and the eigenvalues of $A^tA$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $AA^t$. If $A$ is a matrix with complex entries, then we additionally have to note that $A$ and its complex conjugate $\bar A$ satisfy $\overline{AA^*} = [\bar A][\bar A]^*$, which allows us to conclude that they have the same singular values.

Comment: Dear Bean, My query was different. In particular, in my consideration, underlying Hilbert space was complex Hilbert space.

Comment: The result still applies. As I said, $\|A^t\| = \|A\|$ also holds when $A$ has complex entries

Comment: Now, I got your point. Thank you very much @Ben

Comment: Glad to help.${}$